# inserting a name in a sql DB automaticly capitalize the first character

Tags: sql, vb.net

i am trying to capitalize the first character of a name when i insert the name in an sql DB from a vb.net application! I tried the initcap an the upper function, but didn't work! Is tehre a solution?

Comment: That's something you should do in VB.NET - not in SQL....

Answer (score 4):

The expression is this

```
UPPER(LEFT(@whatever, 1)) + SUBSTRING(@whatever, 2, 8000)
```

Note that the "8000" replaces a LEN(@whatever). An input string of 48 bytes will stay 48 bytes

Comment: @ramajoud1: Please read the FAQ and learn about voting and accepting answers http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work If this works for you, then please accept (the tick on the left) and/or upvote (the up arrow on the left)